# What is "this" referring to when binding event callback function in React component with "null" argument?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bind, dom-events

In [this React tutorial](https://css-tricks.com/learning-react-container-components/#article-header-id-7) a button click event callback function inside a React Presentational Component is bound to `null` explicitely:

```
<button onClick={_this.props.toggleActive.bind(null, user.id)}>Toggle Active</button>
```

However, inside the callback function the `this` keyword is used to access the React Container Component's state:

```
toggleActive: function(userId) {
   ...
   var newState = Object.assign({}, this.state)
   ...
}
```

I do not understand why this example works when `this` should equal `null` or, in non-strict mode, the global `window` object. Can anybody tell me why the example is working anyway?

The corresponding Codepen can be found [here](http://codepen.io/bradwestfall/pen/oxBGRa).

Comment: i don't know exactly, but from my expirience if you pass null as "context" argument it will be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

```
<button onClick={_this.props.toggleActive.bind(null, user.id)}>Toggle Active</button>
```

> Here you are binding method to `null`, not the instance.Hence you can
>   not access `this` within a  method, therefore `this` will not work.

Comment: That is exactly what I was expecting, but like stated in my original question, it does work, which surprised me. My question is why it does work. I think it should fail.

Answer (score 0):

I was wrong earlier and didn't understood the question.Look at following code:-

```
function a(){
    this.x = 5;
    this.y = function(){
        console.log(this.x)
    }
}
var x = 20;
var c = new a();
var d = c.y.bind(null);
d(); // prints 20 and not null or undefined
```

when null is passed as context in bind function, the function retains its original context, i.e global scope here (context in which function d is defined).However, if some context was passed in bind function, the function would have printed 'x' property of that context.

Similarly, when you pass null in

```
<button onClick={_this.props.toggleActive.bind(null, user.id)}>Toggle Active</button>
```

On trigger, the context inside toggleActive function is the context in which it is defined,i.e that of UserListContainer.Hence it is able to access its state

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Do you have any reference where it says that `null` arguments are ignored by bind? The MDN documentation does not mention it at all for example.